# ivars and recurring methods

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cocoa-touch

I have to call a method that is recurring, or in other words the method will call itself.

At the same time I have to have a control variable that the method will use.

First I would thought of declaring an ivar like `controlIndex` and use that inside the method, like this:

```
// declared on .h
NSUInteger controlIndex;

// later on the program...
controlIndex = 100;
[self doItBaby];


...


- (void)doItBaby {

    NSArray *subNodes = [node children];
    if ([subNodes count] == 0) return;

    for (id oneNode in subNodes) {
       if ([oneNode isABomb]) { 
          [oneNode markNodeWithIndex:controlIndex];
          controlIndex ++;
       }
       [self doItBaby];
    }
}
```

this code will do the job but I am using this ivar declared on the main class header.

I wonder if there is a way to self contain the `controlIndex` variable, instead of using that one on the class header.

Comment: Class extension would be other option for self containing the variable to implementation file.

Comment: If the variable is used only within this method, he shouldn't be creating a class category just to contain the variable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor your method to taking an argument.

```
- (void)doItBaby:(NSUInteger)controlIndex {
    NSArray *subNodes = [node children];

    if ([subNodes count] == 0) return;

    for (id oneNode in subNodes) {
        if ([oneNode isABomb]) { 
          [oneNode markNodeWithIndex:controlIndex];
          controlIndex ++;
       }
       [self doItBaby:controlIndex];
    }
}
```

You will still have to send it an initial value and resend the `controlIndex` variable with every recursive call, but your initial value doesn't have to be an instance variable visible to the whole class.

```
[self doItBaby:100];
```

Answer (score 0):

declare `static NSUInteger controlIndex` in `doItBaby`

```
- (void)doItBaby {
   static NSUInteger controlIndex = 100;
}
```

Comment: not working. Every time doItBaby runs, the variable is 100... it is not being incremented.

Comment: This is wrong as the OP is using the variable in the recursive method and static variables are reset each time the method is called - [See here](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/functions.html)